# Add an attribute on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to add an attribute to an `<input />` on focus using js / jQuery?

Right now, off the top of my head, I would think

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').focus(function(){
        $(this).attr(attributeHere);
    });
});
```

Is that correct? Does the attribute have to have quotes around it?

Right now, it is just going to be an attribute with no value. Value will be added later.

Comment: on.("focus",function() {...}); is recommended

Comment: By passing one parameter `attr` returns the value of that attribute, for setting an attribute, you should pass 2 parameters. `attr('attribute', 'value')` and jQuery documentations are _free_.

Comment: @und - So who has been collecting my payments all this time?!?

Comment: @mplungjan why is that recommended? I thought it didn't matter.

Comment: @undefined This attribute has no value.

Comment: `.focus()` is just a shortcut for `on('focus')` - [the documentation clearly states that](http://api.jquery.com/focus/). I like to use the `on` syntax so that all my event definitions have similar syntax - makes everything easier to read IMO. There isn't *really* a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on("focus",function() {
        $(this).attr('name', 'value'); // value could be '' if you would like to specify it later.
    });
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me. Only one thing I would add is that even if you want to leave the attribute empty, you should give it an empty string as a value.

```
var attrName = 'someAttr';
$(this).attr(attrName,'');
```

By not passing a value (even an empty string), you are actually calling the getter function for the attribute where you really want to be calling the setter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this -

```
$(this).attr('attributeName','attributeValue');
```

What you are trying `.attr(attributeName)` is used to access attribute value

> **Description:** Get the value of an attribute for the first element in
>   the set of matched elements.

See the api :

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
.attr( attributeName, value )

attributeName
Type: String   <--  Either a var containing string or an "string" 
The name of the attribute to set.

value
Type: String or Number
A value to set for the attribute.
```